# Почему не работает цикл питон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Пишу этот код:

```
while True:
     b = random.randint(1, 2)

if b == 1:
    print("Поздравляем! Вы получилu 1 btc :)")
    btc = btc + 1
    sp(0.1)

if b == 2:
    print("Не повезло :( попробуй подождать")
    btc = btc * 1
    sp(0.1)
```

В итоге он мне пишет приветствие, которое я написал ранее и застывает помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Он не застывает, он крутиться в бесконечном цикле выбирая случайно 1 или 2, и нет ему другого пути. Можно увидеть это сделав в цикле print(b)

Comment: Не помогает, я даже могу бесконечно нажимать ентер и ничего не происходит (я написал принт б, принт баланс и ничего)

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы срабатывали if, вам перед ними надо поставить отступы, чтобы они попали в цикл while.

Comment: А что такое `sp` - псевдоним для `sleep`? )

Answer (score 1):

правильные отступы должны быть, чтобы все работало как следует

```
import random
btc = 0
while True:
    b = random.randint(1,2)
    if b == 1:
        print("Поздравляем! Вы получилu 1 btc :)")
        btc = btc + 1
        sp(0.1)
    if b == 2:
        print("Не повезло :( попробуй подождать")
        btc = btc * 1
        sp(0.1)
```